# React Native realm get objects return array without values

Tags: react-native, realm

Realm react native returning array of objects without values.

package version in `package.json`

```
"react": "16.11.0",
"react-native": "0.62.2",
"realm": "^6.0.2"
```

node version : `v12.17.0`

react-native-cli: `2.0.1`

Defined `Students` class and schema as below:

```
export class Students {}

Students.schema = {
  name: 'students',
  primaryKey: 'roll_no',
  properties: {
    name: {type: 'string'},
    roll_no: {type: 'string'},
    order: {type: 'int', default: 0},
  },
};
```

Creating realm database object globally:

```
export const realmDatabase = new Realm({
  schema: [Students],
  path: 'school.realm',
  schemaVersion: 1,
});
```

Using below function to insert data into `student` table

```
export function insertStudents(students) {
    realmDatabase.write(() => {
      students.forEach((student) => {
        try {
          realmDatabase.create('students', {
            name: student['name'],
            order: student['order'],
            roll_no: student['roll_no'],
          });
        } catch (error) {}
      });
    });
}
```

Fetch students from database using below function, but it retrieving empty Array of objects

```
export function getStudents() {
  try {
    let students = realmDatabase.objects('students');
    console.log(students);
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

Output :

```
{ '0': {},
  '1': {},
  '2': {},
  '3': {},
  '4': {},
  '5': {},
  '6': {}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue finally, earlier is my Object model is type of `class` and is working fine on older version of realm but now its not working for me for updated version of `realm` and need to change it this as:

In older versions model object like this:

```
export class Students {}

Students.schema = {
  name: 'students',
  primaryKey: 'roll_no',
  properties: {
    name: {type: 'string'},
    roll_no: {type: 'string'},
    order: {type: 'int', default: 0},
  },
};
```

Updated versions :

```
export const Students = {
      name: 'students',
      primaryKey: 'roll_no',
      properties: {
        name: {type: 'string'},
        roll_no: {type: 'string'},
        order: {type: 'int', default: 0},
      },
    };
```